# xml xslt transform

Tags: xml, xslt

I’ve been trying to transform some simple XML into another simple XML using XSLT.  I am new to XSLT, so if someone could give me an example I will expand on it.

I have arbitrary XML files: e.g

```
<element>
 <child_element>
  <grandchild_element>
     only one
  </grandchild_element>
 </child_element>
 <child_element>
  <grandchild_element>
     one
  </grandchild_element>
  <grandchild_element>
     two
  </grandchild_element>
 </child_element>
</element>
```

From which I want to produce:

```
<tree>
 <item class="element" id="1">
  <item class="child_element" id="11">
   <item class="grandchild_element" id="111" value="only one"/>
  </item>
  <item class="child_element" id="12">
   <item class="grandchild_element" id="121" value="only one"/>
   <item class="grandchild_element" id="122" value="only one"/>
  </item>
 </item>
</tree>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One of the simplest/shortest solutions (only 3 templates no modes, no axes, no `count()`, only a single `xsl:attribute`) that is at the same time most generic (works with any element names)**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <tree>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tree>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:variable name="vNumber">
   <xsl:number count="*" level="multiple"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <item class="{name()}"
        id="{translate($vNumber, '.', '')}">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </item>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:attribute name="value">
   <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<element>
 <child_element>
  <grandchild_element>
     only one
  </grandchild_element>
 </child_element>
 <child_element>
  <grandchild_element>
     one
  </grandchild_element>
  <grandchild_element>
     two
  </grandchild_element>
 </child_element>
</element>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tree>
   <item class="element" id="1">
      <item class="child_element" id="11">
         <item class="grandchild_element" id="111" value="only one"/>
      </item>
      <item class="child_element" id="12">
         <item class="grandchild_element" id="121" value="one"/>
         <item class="grandchild_element" id="122" value="two"/>
      </item>
   </item>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd write up a template for each element, like:

```
<xsl:template match="child_element">
```

and use the count of the preceding or preceding-sibling elements to get the "id" field:

```
<xsl:template match="child_element">
    <item>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(preceding-sibling::element),count(preceding::child_element)+1)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </item>
</xsl:template>
```

For the grandchild-id, you'll have to play around with .. and preceding-sibling.
I'd however strongly advise you not to use your current counting scheme for id's anyway: Once you have more than 10 nodes at any level, collisions occur.

Answer (score 0):

To get the **id** for each element, you will need look back at each of the ancestors, and for each level, count the number of preceding-siblings.

```
<xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="id"/>
</xsl:attribute>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="id">
   <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

To convert the element name into the **class** attribute is straight-forward, and done like so:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class">
   <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

And to convert text into the **value** attribute is also fairly simple.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
   <xsl:attribute name="value">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
   </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

The **normalize-space** here is to remove the line-breaks shown in your sample XML.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <!-- Match root element -->
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <tree>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </tree>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Match any element in the XML -->
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <item>
         <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::*" mode="id"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:attribute name="class">
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
         </xsl:attribute>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </item>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Used to match ancestors to work out the id -->
   <xsl:template match="*" mode="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Convert text into the value attribute -->
   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:attribute name="value">
         <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Copy any existing attributes in the XML -->
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<tree>
   <item id="1" class="element">
      <item id="11" class="child_element">
         <item id="111" class="grandchild_element" value="only one"/>
      </item>
      <item id="12" class="child_element">
         <item id="121" class="grandchild_element" value="one"/>
         <item id="122" class="grandchild_element" value="two"/>
      </item>
   </item>
</tree>
```